# scan or query data by deleted column

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a boolean "deleted" column in my database and I'm trying to scan all records that are not deleted (it's a soft delete)

```
      var scanParams = {
        TableName: "students",
        FilterExpression: "deleted = :deleted",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":deleted": false,
        },
      };

      const scan = await db.scan(scanParams).promise();
```

this does not return any data because I'm not storing my records with deleted = false. I only add deleted = true when the records are deleted.

[image]

I tried with

```
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":deleted": "",
        },
```

but now I get no records at all. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reverse your scan condition - Get items that have `delete` is NOT true.

```
 var scanParams = {
        TableName: "students",
        FilterExpression: "deleted <> :deleted", // NOT EQUAL TRUE -> empty or false
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":deleted": true,
        },
      };

      const scan = await db.scan(scanParams).promise();
```

Comment: good idea/ can I apply the same logic while using db.get ? because that  returns a given row by id (in my case)